# How to use directional arrows in TextView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, unicode

What's the correct way to use directional arrows within a `TextView` without having to create a drawable? Unicode has been thought of but it's not clear which character codes need be used. What code must be used both for HTML and programmatically for the left, right, up & down arrows? Ideally to get the same result as the arrows used in the screenshots below (notice how they are correctly autosized and positioned in line as the text).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right you can use **Unicode** like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="&#8594; right" />


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="&#8592; left" />


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="&#8593; top" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="&#8595; bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I use this [site](https://unicode-table.com/en/) it has a lot of data for arrows section check [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrow-symbols/)